# highcharts tooltip not moving next point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, highcharts

I tried this code but tool-tip only showing the starting and end value. But what I want is showing tool-tip to all values.

How can I show tool-tip to all values of high-chart? *-"From first next to the other points when hovering"*

This is my full code:

```js
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      zoomType: 'y'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'FlexiMc'
    },
    xAxis: {
      type: 'datetime',
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      //max: 90000,
      title: {
        text: 'Exchange rate'
      }
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: true
    },
    tooltip: {
      valueDecimals: 2,
      valueSuffix: '',
    },
    series: [{
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Current Out',
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 18, 33), 0],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 17, 42), 0],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 16, 40), 10.83],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 16, 21), 14.83],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 14, 43), 86.34],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 13, 46), 72.35],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 12, 40), 31.69],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 11, 42), 133.37]
      ],
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 3
      },
      shadow: true,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        shared: true
      }
    }, {
      type: 'line',
      name: 'Voltage',
      data: [
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 18, 33), 5.13],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 17, 42), 219],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 16, 40), 644],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 16, 21), 652],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 14, 43), 664],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 13, 46), 628],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 12, 40), 668],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 11, 42), 652],
        [Date.UTC(2014, 10, 12, 10, 46), 648]
      ],
      marker: {
        enabled: true,
        radius: 3
      },
      shadow: true,
      tooltip: {
        valueDecimals: 2,
        shared: true
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

So, it appears you might be getting hung up in JSON formatting. That'd be my first guess, in fact. So, I see you've started with one of their demo charts -- the one about weather and whatnot. Is that example, in particular, REALLY close to what you're going for? If not, your best be would be to start **[~~HERE~~](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#chart)**, as it lists all of their options, and is already set-up to be copied and pasted (at least roughly) after you've expanded all of the options you're interested in.

Just keep your json formatted well. A quick way to fix the spacing issues would be to assign that object literal you're passing in to a variable and `console.log(JSON.stringify(chartVar, null, 4))` this should print it out nicely. You could copy and paste from there.

#### TL;DR I would personally start with one of the more basic examples that have most of what I want, put my own data in, and get it working in the simplest possible form... Then go crazy with custom labels, colors, and such.

Hope your eyes are tired. :P

Answer (score 0):

Your data needs to be sorted via x, ascending.